# Unable to launch .exe application in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have written a windows service to launch a sample windows application. Once the service loads it should start the application but in my case even though service starts it is not able to launch my application.

Below is the code:

```
  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.WriteToFile("Simple Service started {0}");
        Process.Start("‪D:\\demo.exe");
        this.WriteToFile("Simple Service ended {0}");

    }
```

Comment: Have you verified the path whether it exists there or not?

Comment: What the security context of the windows service?

Comment: Even if the service does launch the application, it will be running in Session 0, not the session of any logged in user(s). If you're trying to launch an *interactive* application, this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It might be your service running with `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem` account

Goto your ServiceInstaller.cs file

Goto InitializeComponent() method

Please change below line as per your code

`this.serviceProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.User`

NOTE: It will ask windows login id / password while service installation.

please read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceaccount(v=vs.110).aspx) wonderfule artical of MSDN

Answer (score 0):

```
  ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("‪D:\\demo.exe");
  pinfo.Verb = "runas";
  Process.Start(pinfo);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Comment: I tried with the above code but doesn't work :( Log what i have written executes fine but .exe file doesn't work :(

Comment: Oops, Oh, I've also tried this service running exe code once. After spending 2 days finding solution , I reached at the conclusion that a background running service isn't capable of starting a UI process. But if you find any solution, kindly do post it here, because I wanna know